# How to call a CCK Field value in a node

Tags: theming, 6, entities

I want to load one last post's title and call value of CCK fields. I defensibly don't want to use views module. so How can I call those CCK Fields?

anyway is this code correct to load one last post from all terms? 
I wish there was a way to do it with node_load()

```
<?PHP
$output = '';
$terms = "*";
$count = 15;
$qry = "SELECT n.title, n.nid FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {term_node} tn ON n.nid = tn.nid WHERE tn.tid in ($terms) AND n.status=1 AND n.promote=1 ORDER BY n.created DESC";
$result = db_query_range(db_rewrite_sql($qry), 0, $count);
$output = node_title_list($result);
echo $output;
// echo [cck_field1_value];
// echo [cck_field2_value];
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will tell you that the easier way it to use `node_load`. You do your query to simply get the last nodes according your criteria and then with the `nid` you load each node with `node_load`.

Why ? Because CCK changes his database structure according the fields that are attached or not to one or more content type. If you will change the CCK field one day, you will have to change your code, so the easier way to avoid it, its simply use `node_load`.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't really understand. I just need to print last node with CCK fields I specified and node title. not body, teaser or ... do you mean it's not possible ?

Comment: No, I just mean get the nid with a sql query (like : `SELECT nid FROM node ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1`) and then load the node with `node_load` and you will get all informations you need.